# Adding custom component interspersed within related lists on standard detail page

Tags: opportunity, pageblocksection

Is there a way to add a complete new section "Related list" to an opportunity.
[image]

and then have check box field with  a search users option and assigning date.
do I need to create this in apex , or can I do it using salesforce itself, I know about the page layout, but I want that section be between "Notes&Attachments" and Quots

Comment: Based on what you're describing, you're talking about generating a custom VisualForce page that 'looks' like a related list.  To my knowledge, VisualForce elements have to be part of the main (top) section of the page layout.  So you would not be able to insert a custom element in between the related lists, unless you rebuild the entire page.  (Not an answer, because I'm not 100% certain)

Comment: @HomerJ yah, I have to see if I can create that new section between related lists

Comment: I came across this already, we can not add section in the related list.

Comment: @Suri is there a way around it, how would I add stuff to this page

Comment: this can probably be done by using a 1) VF page with apex:detail; 2) your custom component added to the end of the page; 3) jQuery magic to rearrange the DOM to insert your custom component in the spot where you want. Result may be fragile as it will depend on SFDC HTML generation done by apex:detail for jQuery to be able to find the right spots

Comment: @crop1645 so in other words, it cant be done lol

Comment: No @bez it can be done, but either easily but different or exactly as you want with a hell of effort. It's up to you to choose. I would recommend to add the section simply above where all the sections are and not at the related list.

Comment: I did such jQuery magic as @crop1645 described several times and it's very stable. Some users love it. But it's out of warranty. Caveat Emptor. You have to invest the implementation and babysit the solution if you are picky enough to choose the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this issue

**Replace page with VF page (without using apex:detail)**

Use `apex:pageBlock`, `apex:pageBlockSection`, and `apex:outputFields` to replicate your page. If you want inlineedit support you'll need to enable that as well with the requisite VF components for those parts of the page where this is important to you

Insert `apex:relatedList` components in the order you desire

Insert your custom component between the apex:relatedLists

*Drawbacks (many)*

1. You lose the hover links at the top of the page to the related lists. There are workarounds to this involving a 1) custom component and custom controller or 2) clever Javascript hack that borrows from SFDC javascript functions.
2. Some related lists can't be reconstructed using apex:relatedList.  For example, field history and SalesforceToSalesforce related lists - these require creation of yet more custom components with associated controller
3. You lose the ability to re-arrange fields with the page layout editor. This can be mitigated with fieldSets

**Replace page with VF page and keep apex:detail**

Build a simple VF page using `apex:detail` and your custom component (which appears after `apex:detail`)

Use `jQuery` to manipulate the DOM by moving the custom component div in between the DOM elements for the two related lists where you want the custom component to reside

*Drawbacks*

1. None from the first option; you get hover links and all related lists.
2. The solution is, as @UweHeim says, 'out of warranty' as it may break if SFDC changes the way it constructs the DOM for an apex:detail page.

Personally, I'd go for option 2 as it won't take more than a few lines of jQuery after careful study of the generated DOM using Firebug or Chrome developer tools.  I've re-arranged and auto-collapsed pageBlockSections based on user profile using this technique